# Ignore sub module root folder

Tags: git, github

[image]

I have these file structure. Now node_modules is an added sub module.

This structure is similar to the master branch. Now I want that the master branch looks like this but the deployment branch exclude the node_modules sub module but I want to use the node_modules sub module in the local.

How will I ignore the node_modules sub module properly?

I added an entry in the .gitignore like this

```
/node_modules/
```

But it does not work. It still uploaded the node_modules on the remote repo.

To understand this properly, what I want is that I can update the folder as a sub module locally but I don't want to push the sub module in the remote repository.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a .gitignore file doesn't automatically remove objects that have already been committed.  If you do `git rm --cached node_modules` and then commit, you can remove it from the index.

Comment: I did this and it remove the node_modules but node_modules is now not a recognize sub module even the folder is still existing. So I cannot update it properly locally.